# How can I merge two dataframes not by values but by ranges of values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Dataframe A:

```
pd.Dataframe({
    'price': [50, 150, 250], 
    'group':[2, 5, 10]
})
```

Dataframe B:

```
pd.Dataframe({
    'low_price': [0, 100, 200], 
    'high_price': [99, 199, 299],
    'low_group':[0, 4, 8],
    'high_group':[3, 6, 12],
    'something':['A', 'B', 'C']
})
```

How can I merge these dataframes on a condition like:
- Dataframe A's price is **between** Dataframe B's low and high prices.
AND
- Dataframe A's group is **between** Dataframe B's low and high groups.

Is there a way to do this **without iterating** through rows and checking one by one? I already did it like that and it costs O(n^2), not scalable.

---

**EDIT**:

PS1: Every row in A has 0 or 1 match in B. I'm looking for an "inner" merge.

PS2: A has millions of records, B has hundreds.

Comment: 1) can a row in A match multiple rows in B? 2) Will every row in A match a row in B? 3) What are the lengths of A and B in your actual data?

Comment: 1) No. 2) Nope. 3) A: millions of records, B: hundreds. Thank you, I updated the description.

Comment: What do you mean by merging two data? What's your expected output for the given two?

Answer (score 0):

If your data is already sorted, you may be able to get it down to O(log n) if you implement some sort of binary search to find where to partition the data (Assuming the merge process doesn't take more than O(log n) as well).

If your data isn't sorted, the best you could do would be O(n), merging at the same time as you discover a merge candidate.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot easily do that for simultaneously price and group, but `merge_asof` can join the relevant low_price of B for each row from A in one single pass. Then a query of a selection with `loc` will only keep rows meeting other conditions.

```
pd.merge_asof(A, B, left_on='price', right_on='low_price').query(
    '(price<=high_price)&(group>=low_group)&(group<=high_group)')
```